# Crop featured image by default

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm having trouble finding out how to accomplish this - I want to display a cropped version of an image in the post. So when it's uploaded, it would automatically be displayed cropped. Is there any way to do that? For example, [this would be the original image uploaded](http://kineticcreative.co/1.jpg) and [this is what it would look like in the post](http://kineticcreative.co/2.jpg)

Is there a way to set that cropping be default? It would be great if the user would upload the image already cropped, but if they don't, I want to have a fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

1. define a custom image size ([add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size))

   add_image_size(name,w,h,true);

   where `w` and `h` for height and width of your image.and fourth parameter true for hard croping of image.read wordpress codex for that
2. put your custom image size name in [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) function

   the_post_thumbnail('name')

or

if your design is not responsive then you can set image size using css.

```
--class/id-- img{
width:w;
height:h;
}
```

Comment: The site is responsive, but that first solution should work. Thanks!! I somehow overlooked that crop part

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom image size as in above answer and use it with the the_post_thumbnail function.
If you don't want to do this and want to apply the crop to all the featured images then there is a more simple solution than this.

In wordpress admin, goto

Settings->Media.

There you can set thumbnail size and there is also an option for cropping to exact dimension. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php set_post_thumbnail_size( $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

This function allows you to register additional image sizes for Featured Images, set $crop parameter to `true`

[See codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size)